# Error al entrar en la interface de Cloudpanel

Tags: login

Desde hace unos días cuando intento entrar en la interface web de Cloudpanel me pide usuario contraseña desde un Popup, cuando lo normal es que salga la interface de Cloud panel, introduzco el usuario contraseña en el Popup y me indica que no es correcto, si lo cancelo me da error, lo hago por el puerto 8443 y he verificado por ssh que el usuario y contraseña es correcto, ante la duda incluso he cambiado la contraseña pero nada, ¿le ha pasado a alguien más? ¿a que se puede deber?
Añado captura de pantalla
[image: captura]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.